DSolve solves the PDE in Wolfram Mathematica, but not in Wolfram Cloud
Good evening!
I have the following Mathematica code.
Clear["Global`*"]
PDE = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 4}]
bound1 = u[0, t] == 0
bound2 = u[Pi, t] == 0
bound3 = Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == Exp[-4 t]
bound4 = Derivative[1, 0][u][Pi, t] == -(Cosh[Pi]) Exp[-4 t]
init = u[x, 0] == Sin[x] Cosh[x]
DSolve[{PDE, bound1, bound2, bound3, bound4, init}, 
  u[x, t], {x, t}] // FullSimplify

It works perfectly in Wolfram Mathematica. However, in Wolfram Cloud, I get the following error messages:

General solution is not available for the given linear partial differential equation. Trying to build a particular solution.
For somebranches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution.

Why is this happening?
Thanks in advance!

I get same exact messages using Mathematica V 14. (not cloud).  Which versions are you using that did not show this message?  https://i.sstatic.net/4ZY0hVLj.png

On my windows 10, I get same exact messages using Mathematica V 14. (not cloud).The same mesages like user @Nasser.

@Nasser , , thanks for your answer! I am using version 13.3. Do you think it could be an issue with the version? I thought it was restrictions related to the free versions.

@MariuszIwaniuk , thanks for your answer! I am using Wolfram Mathematica 13.3. However, I am also using Wolfram Engine 14 in Jupyter notebook. Version 13.3 gives me an answer (u[x, t] -> E^(-4 t) Cosh[x] Sin[x]), but version 14 does not.

Yes I tried version 13.3 and works fine. Yes is a Bug.

@MariuszIwaniuk , I understand. Thank you. Do you think I should report the problem somewhere so that it can be fixed?

I send e-mail to WRI about this bug.

@MariuszIwaniuk, ok. Thanks!
